# Paypal error 10002: Authentication/Authorization Failed

Tags: paypal, express, authorization, checkout

I'm trying to implement Paypal's Express Checkout and I keep getting an 10002 error. I'm 100% sure my API credentials are correct, I also have Express Checkout enabled in my Seller account.

I can make the **SetExpressCheckout** call. That should mean my API details are correct (if I change them, I cannot make the call anymore). I'm only pasting these parameters:

```
'CURRENCYCODE'=>$currency,
'PAYMENTACTION' =>'Sale',
'RETURNURL' => $this->returnURL,
'CANCELURL'  => $this->cancelURL,
'NOSHIPPING'=>"1",
'METHOD' =>'SetExpressCheckout',
'AMT' =>$amount,
'DESC'=>$desc
```

However, when I get the payment confirmation from Paypal (e.g. http://site.com/index.php?p1=payment&p2=payment_confirmation_paypal&token=EC-1SH98151XXX192835&PayerID=6G95XXXNQ333L) and I call the **DoExpressCheckoutPayment** and **GetExpressCheckoutDetails** methods, I always get the 10002 error:

```
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Authentication/Authorization Failed
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => You do not have permissions to make this API call
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
```

Thanks a lot if you have any idea what may cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the same credentials are being passed over in the Get and Do API calls that you are sending over in the Set.  Also make sure the endpoint is correct as well for all 3 API calls.  Also, make sure that you are not passing over the variable "SUBJECT" and setting an email address as the value.  If you are, and are wanting to use 3rd party permissions than you need to make sure the account you are trying to run the API call on has the correct permissions granted to it.